Opening rasterio datasets in threads
I have an application that requires opening a lot of GeoTIFFs, and I would like to do it concurrently. Basically, I am calling rasterio.open() in each thread and storing the resulting DatasetReader objects in a list. Here is the most basic example of what I am trying to do:
import rasterio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait


def rio_open(path: str) -> rasterio.io.DatasetReader:
    return rasterio.open(path)

tiffs = ... # a REALLY LONG list of GeoTIFF files, all different

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    futs = [executor.submit(rio_open, t) for t in tiffs]
    wait(futs)

    dsets = [f.result() for f in futs]

This works, but it is much slower than I would expect. In fact, this is slower than opening up the GeoTIFFs serially e.g., :
dsets = [rio_open(t) for t in tiffs]

After some debugging, I've observed that the rasterio.open() calls in the threads are not happening concurrently; it's like there is a lock somewhere (and this would explain why it's a little slower than not multi-threading at all).
Even more confusing is that, if I use processes instead of threads, this apparent locking seems to go away. So this code
import rasterio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, wait


def rio_open(path: str) -> None:
    # can't return this anymore since DatasetReader is not serializable :-(
    rasterio.open(path)

tiffs = ... # a REALLY LONG list of GeoTIFF files, all different

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    futs = [executor.submit(rio_open, t) for t in tiffs]
    wait(futs)

executes really fast, about 8x faster than just opening the files sequentially. The problem with this version is that I can't return the DatasetReader objects using processes, since they are not serializable.
I am wondering if there is a fundamental reason why the thread-based implementation is not working as I would expect, or if maybe I need to set an option somewhere that allows me to do what I need.

The python interpreter is not thread safe, so locks are in place so only one thread at a time can run python code. If you want to know more about that, search for "python GIL".
This doesn't mean that not any parallellization is possible using threads in python. Reading files from a hard disk par example is something that is handled for the most part by operating system code, so not in python interpreted code, so this will happen in parallel when using threads. Also, many python libraries actually contain a lot of C code under the hood, so when the C code is thread-safe (also often not he case) the developers can specify in the python wrapper code that this is the case to enable real multi-threading.
So, sometimes multithreading will help for performance, often it won't.
This is why in python multiprocessing is often the only way to get speed improvements, but it is a bit harder to get working and for some use cases the overhead will be larger than the gains, especially on windows where starting a process is quite "expensive" compared to on linux...
As multithreading doesn't give the expected improvements, you'll probably have to think if your use case can be "massaged" in a way that multiprocessing becomes feasable.
E.g I often need to calculate zonal statistics between a vector file and many raster files, which can take quite some time for large datasets. So, to avoid having to share data between processes, each process reads the vector and raster data needed itself, does the calculations and writes away the result to file. This way multiprocessing works fine. It's not 100% optimal but, for this use case, good enough.

That makes sense, thanks!
I found a work-around that raises even more questions for me. Basically, I can concurrently open() GeoTIFF files and wrap them in a BytesIO, and then sequentially call rasterio.open on those objects.
The opening and converting to BytesIO does seem to be parallelizable, so I do get the speed-up I expected to begin with.
I find it a bit confusing and frustrating that rasterio isn't able to do something like this natively...

It's difficult to judge what is really happening because it depends on your exact usage, and where the performance bottlenecks are located. Concurrently reading the files to a BytesIO will indeed work as it is ~only disk IO, which will be handled by your OS. Rasterio often will be used differently. Instead of just reading all bytes as they are from disk, often only a part of the file will be read, and the data will have to be decoded because it will often be compressed,... So the exact usage can give big differences to the best appraoch to take.
